# Find a pattern in string and replace it

Tags: c#, regex

I need to parse the following format `@[Alphanumeric1](Alphanumeric2:Alphanumeric3)` from a long string. Below is my string:

```
This is a long text 
@[Alphanumeric1](Alphanumeric2:Alphanumeric3) again long text 
@[Alphanumeric11](Alphanumeric22:Alphanumeric33) again long text
@[Alphanumeric111](Alphanumeric222:Alphanumeric333)
```

I need all the occurence of(`@[Alphanumeric1](Alphanumeric2:Alphanumeric3)`) to be replaced by value which is coming after colon(:) i.e I want the output as

```
This is a long text 
Alphanumeric3 again long text 
Alphanumeric33 again long text
Alphanumeric333
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string data = @"This is a long text 
@[Alphanumeric1](Alphanumeric2:Alphanumeric3) again long text 
@[Alphanumeric11](Alphanumeric22:Alphanumeric33) again long text
@[Alphanumeric111](Alphanumeric222:Alphanumeric333)";

        Debug.WriteLine(ReplaceData(data));
    }

    private static string ReplaceData(string data)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(data, @"@\[.+?\]\(.*?:(.*?)\)", match => match.Groups[1].ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`@\[[\w\d]*\]\([\w\d]*:([\w\d]*)\)`

That will match the three strings above, and grab the alphanumeric string after the `:` in group **1**. [Play with the regex here](http://regexr.com?31ll1).

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should by able to handle that input:

```
(@\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+\]\([a-zA-Z0-9]+:(?<match>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\))
```

Used in C#, the following will find & replace all instances in a string `input`:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(@\[[a-zA-Z0-9]+\]\([a-zA-Z0-9]+:(?<match>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\))", "${match}");
```

Regex Explained:

```
(                           # beginning of group to find+replace
    @                       # match the '@'
    \[                      # match the '['
        [a-zA-Z0-9]+        # alpha-numeric match
    \]                      # match the ']'
    \(                      # match the '('
        [a-zA-Z0-9]+        # alpha-numeric match
        :                   # match the ':'
        (?<match>           # beginning of group to use for replacement
            [a-zA-Z0-9]+    # alpha-numeric match
        )
    \)                      # match the ')'
)
```